# How do I access a SVN server remotely?

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I set up a [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) server on a Windows machine. How do I access that repository via terminal from a different Ubuntu (Linux) machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for WIndows or [SubDiverSVN](http://subdiversvn.sourceforge.net/) for Linux -- they are UI based utility. Or install a [command-line SVN](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/subversion.html) and perform

```
svn list <url_to_your_repository>  //to list the folders
svn co  <url_to_your_repository>   //to checkout the code
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install a subversion client on Ubuntu.  Run this on the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Further information on how to use the client can be found in the Ubuntu Help Section:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion#Access Methods